# Django South, add new model

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-south

For some reason, when I add a new model and use Django South to sync the database by: /manage.py schemamigration myapp --auto and then the migrate line, I still can't see the model on the admin page. 
South does say that it added the model though.. so I'm not sure what's going on..

Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you register your app with the admin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just because you created the model and synced it, does not mean it gets added to the admin page automatically. You must create an `admin.py` file in your app directory that contains

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import MyModel

admin.site.register(MyModel)
```

and make sure you have `admin.site.autodiscover()` in your main urls.py

This should all be covered in the tutorial pages for Django. Go back and RTM.

Comment: =) perfect! I knew i was forgetting something!